# Conda create environment ignoring rccPostInstall

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, robocopy

I have been following Robocop tutorial and while creating a conda environment came across following warning

EnvironmentSectionNotValid: The following section on '/home/ubuntu/sandbox/rpadryrun/conda.yml' is invalid and will be ignored:

- rccPostInstall

The conda.yml file looks like following

```
name: rpadryrun
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.5
  - pip=20.1
  - nodejs=16.14.2
  - pip:
    - rpaframework==13.0.0
    - robotframework-browser==12.2.0
rccPostInstall:
  - rfbrowser init
```

(The reference link for the example is https://github.com/robocorp/rpaframework).

Not sure why `rccPostInstall` is ignored and the command inside that is not executed.

**Update 1**
Used `conda env create -f conda.yml` to create the environment.

Comment: what command that you use to creating a conda environtemnt?

Comment: Added command details in the question.

Comment: That’s some sort of Domain-Specific Language that is specialized to that toolset. Conda does not support that directly. I’m not familiar, but seems like you have to use their `rcc` tool to create things. https://robocorp.com/docs/rcc/overview